# How does Unix implement file permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

I have a text file named `foo.txt` with root permission in one Linux distribution. I copied it to another Linux distribution on another computer.

Would file permissions be still maintained for `foo.txt`?

If yes, how does Unix/Linux linux know, and duplicate the permissions of the file?

Does it add extra bytes (which indicates the permissions) to the file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add Eric's answer (don't have rep to comment), permissions are not stored in file but file's [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) (filesystem's pointer to the file's physical location on disk) as metadata along with owner and timestamps. This means that copying file to non-POSIX filesystem like NTFS or FAT will drop the permission and owner data.

File owner and group is just a pair of numbers, user ID (UID) and group ID (GID) respectively. Root UID is 0 as standard so file will show up as owned by root on (almost) every unix-compliant system. On the other hand, non-root owner will not be saved in meaningful way.

So in short, root ownership will be preserved if tarball'd or copied via extX usbstick or the like. Non-root ownership is unreliable.

Comment: For the (clearly somewhat novice) OP you might add that you can think of the file's inode as being maintained inside the _directory_ that contains the file rather than in the file itself. Even if technically this might be a bit less accurate than what you say. In any case the  essential point is that a file being copied identically (either within its file system or to a different one) does not rule out that its ownership/permissions might change.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen That explanation can also plant a misconception, so I will add this. Multiple directory entries can point to the same inode. Like after `ln f1 f2`, the `f1` and `f2` files share the same inode. So if you `chmod` any of them, the permissions of both will change at once (as the permissions are actually stored outside the directory entry, in the shared inode).

Answer (score 4):

That would depend on how you copy it.  If you put it in a `tar` ball and copied that, then untarred it, `tar` will perserve permissions.  If you use `rsync` it will also, depending on flags, perserve permissions.  Those applications are responsible for the permissions.  If you were to `scp` it permissions would not be preserved.

The command doing the copying is responsible for managing the permissions on the newly created file.

Comment: `tar` will preserve ownership and permissions *unless* its `o` option is given. Yes, that's completely logical.

Comment: By default `tar` will store information about both the name and id of the owner. When extracting `tar` will by default use the name which was stored, but can be instructed to use only the id.

Comment: It might be worth stressing that `tar` can only preserve ownership when run as root. There is no way for an ordinary user to create files owned by someone else.

Answer (score 0):

For owner/group, it depends on who does the copy, and how.

- a regular user: will alway be the owner of the copies by all commands
- `root` user too, with `cp` (except with the `--preserve` option)
- "preserve" will be the default for `root` with `tar`